# Pulling "LEFT" data up to a specific character

Tags: t-sql, variables

I searched and found this suggestion on how to pull the Prefix of a part number in our database -

```
   Left(ADHOC.ATS_ESH.Customs_Entry_Num,
        Instr(ADHOC.ATS_ESH.Customs_Entry_Num,"-")-1)
   AS Prefix
```

It doesn't seem to work . . .

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using SQL-Server, since your tag says T-SQL. If so, you need to use `CHARINDEX`, it's the equvalant of Instr() in Oracle. The basic syntax is (from [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)):

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

You can find more information [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

Comment: thanks, Arun....I am a very amateur SQL person, but i tried..    ,Left(ADHOC.ATS_ESH.Customs_Entry_Num,Charindex(ADHOC.ATS_ESH.Customs_Entry_Num,'-')-1) AS Prefix     and it still isnt working.   Thoughts ? Much appreciated. NOTE:  "ADHOC...Entry_Num" is the Table.field with the -

Comment: @JeffGreen Whats the error your are getting? Can you make a fiddle with dummy data, so we can see whats happening. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The report crashes when i run it with the generic - "An error occured during report processing"....Cannot read next data row for the dataset

Comment: Create an example on sqlfiddle.com, and send us the link.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
  declare @string varchar(200);
  set @string = 'prefix-suffix';
  select @string;
  select CHARINDEX('-', @string);  
  select left(@string, CHARINDEX('-', @string) - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Blam, but still being thick here, I apologize . . . my actual table.field is called ADHOC.ATS_ESH.Entry_Num.   do replace all of the "@string" with my actual table.field?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you give it a try?   You had CHARINDEX parameter in the wrong spot.  I get you are new to this but you when you have problem you need to break it down to find the source.

Comment: If you are getting an error reading from the dataset that is separate.